# JavaDoc not shown for ActiveMQ in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, activemq-classic

I'm using `activemq-all-5.11.1.jar` as a library in a NetBeans project. Now i want to show the according doc from here: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.11.0/apidocs/.

For that i tried to add the above url to the JavaDoc tab in the Java Platform Manager. But that does not work. By pressing Ctrl-Space in the editor NetBeans always tell me 'Javadoc not found'.

My proxy settings in the options are ok. Pressing 'Test connection' says ok.

What do i need to do to show the corresponding doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a normal Java project you can achieve it like

1. **create first a library**
   click in the project on "Libraries", which will open the dialog "Add Library"
   name it as you which, e.g. "activemq-all"
   click "Add JAR/Folder..." to add the JAR file
   select the JAR file and click "Add URL", and point it to the online javadoc URL
2. **add this library to the project**
   back in the "Add Library" dialog, click on "Add Library"
   you will see the library add to your project with a pile of books icon

If your project is a maven project you cannot achieve it, as the project does not provide a javadoc artifact. Normally you would right click on the maven dependency and select "Download Javadoc". You can only add the javadoc which is locally available as JAR or ZIP. Therefore you would first need to build it yourself.

**edit** To create the javadoc yourself following steps would be needed.
This would actually build for each module. The javadoc is generated for version `5.11.2-SNAPSHOT` which is the current latest `5.11.x` version. There is no separate branch for version `5.11.1`.

1. **clone the branch**
   `git clone -b activemq-5.11.x --single-branch https://github.com/apache/activemq.git`
2. **build the javadoc**
   `mvn clean install javadoc:jar -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

There is no uber-javadoc for `activemq-all`.

Comment: It's a normal project. The trick with the library works but i would prefer to show the doc within the editor not from a website.Ok, now i would like to 'build it myself'. What is a good way to do that? Download the html files with wget and zip that?